# Are there any formulas that compute the coordinate of the spiral numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Just like the title I want to ask about formula for $n \times n$ spiral matrix. In particular, I want to know if there's a formula for a given entry in the matrix, without computing the full matrix.

Here is an example of the kind of matrix I'm talking about:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2&  3&  4&  5&  6 \\
20& 21& 22& 23& 24&  7 \\
19& 32& 33& 34& 25&  8 \\
18& 31& 36& 35& 26&  9 \\
17& 30& 29& 28& 27& 10 \\
16& 15& 14& 13& 12& 11
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: google is your friend : https://www.google.pl/search?q=spiral+matrix&oq=spiral+matrix&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4176j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yeah I've search that term before but that's not what I mean
I want to know what the number by just knowing the coordinate

Comment: **Hint:** recursive with each time taking the inner $n-1$ matrix block; for each layer you go in you add $4n-4$, so something like this:

if (i > 1, k > 1)
return (4n-4) + degree(i-1, k-1, minor(n-1))
else return ...

Comment: i'll leave the else part for you to figure out.

Comment: @ThuậnNguyễn I tried to clarify what I think you're asking, based on the comments (since you've gotten two comments about how one could programmatically *create* such a matrix, but that doesn't appear to be what you're interested in). Feel free to roll back my edit, to your original phrasing, or revise further.